# Look at text in div2 match to div1 and show a button

Tags: jquery, regex, text, show, string-matching

I want to match two bits of text on pageload. So if text in div2 matches div1 at least with 4 or more characters I show a button. If the text does not match I want to show a different button.

I would love to place the match text in a string that I could verify against in a form, but this is user generated text that I need to check if the user has used the same text.

Is this even possible?

Comment: check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/agqevxwn/

Comment: Man alive Pekka, by jove I think you have done it. Nice work. I will try this out and see if it works.

Comment: go try it and well see what we can do to improve it

Comment: Hmm looked so good, but can't seem to get it to work. Might be a conflict somewhere. Its on a woocommerce cart page and I am looking at filename uploads, thats represented as text on the cart page. Does your script work with classes instead of IDs?

Comment: OK So I have gone through all the conflicts and can't see that there is anything blocking it. I have now loaded the script in the site's head and its coming with this error: 'code' TypeError: $ is not a function. Obviously deleting this does not work, so a I am as bit stuck...

Comment: your missing the jquery script

Comment: I have jquery version 1.11.3 loaded in the head...did you mean that or declaring jQuery somewhere else?

Comment: that one is there no conflict?no other script that may be using the $?

Comment: try using jQuery. is it inside `document.ready`?

Comment: the script is all by its lonesome in a file that is called in the head. Would you mind updating the fiddle so I can see what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with enqueing the script in the functions.php. Like so:

```
function custom_script() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'cart_filenames', get_template_directory_uri() . '/framework/js/filename.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_script' );
```

And Pekka I add your code in the filename.js, so thankyou very much for your help.